# Provide a name for visual in PowerBI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

we have recently started using Power BI embedded.
Our basic need is to embed a single visual in a web page.
I found the GetVisuals() method that list the visual and then, given the [Name] property, we can easily set that visual HIDDEN or VISIBLE:

The main issue is : How can I set the visual name when I create the report in PBI Desktop ?

Thanks
ALberto

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the visual name, but if you change the visual title to be different from the default title, then getVisuals() will also return the title:

```
[
  {
    "name": "16d4ed6901e80ab46280",
    "type": "lineChart",
    "title": "Total SalesAmount by Color",
    "layout": {
      "x": 10,
      "y": 20,
      "z": 1,
      "width": 280,
      "height": 280,
      "displayState": {
        "mode": 0
      }
    }
  }
]
```